# Issue when running pyinstaller EXE on other pc - SSL

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Im getting an error when running an exe on a pc that has been generated with PyInstaller:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "export_delivery_note.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "connect.py", line 12, in connect
  File "xmlrpc\client.py", line 1122, in __call__
  File "xmlrpc\client.py", line 1464, in __request
  File "xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in request
  File "xmlrpc\client.py", line 1178, in single_request
  File "xmlrpc\client.py", line 1291, in send_request
  File "xmlrpc\client.py", line 1321, in send_content
  File "http\client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 976, in send
  File "http\client.py", line 1455, in connect
  File "ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)
`
```

When i copy paste this Exe to another pc with the same setup it works.
Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that SSL Certificate Verification Error, As it is checking local certificates it maybe of multiple reasons. Few quick fixes maybe

1. Check your machine time
2. Clear you caches
3. Check you network connection properly

These maybe failure for the local certificates.

Comment: was allready onto that. everything works properly. Note that this in a VM on a NAS. (windows VM)